# Efficient Xorshift skip ahead

Tags: c++, algorithm, random

I need a fast random number generator that allows me to randomly access numbers at various positions of the random number sequence. I chose Xorshift, because it's fast and easy to implement.

To get a specific random number from the sequence, I implemented the following method (`mPos` saves the position of the next random number):

```
void XorshiftRandomGenerator::skipTo(unsigned int pos)
{
    // Reset if we passed the position
    if (mPos>pos)
        reset();

    // Generate random numbers until we're done
    while (mPos<pos)
        random();
}
```

A subsequent `random()` will return the desired number, but this method is very expensive. Is there a way to skip a large amount of random numbers with Xorshift, without calculating every random number in between?

As an alternative I could go with another random number generator. Could you suggest one that allows fast skipping ahead?

Comment: I think a linear congruential generator should let you skip ahead fairly easily (i.e. in logarithmic time).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a 1994 Paper by Forest B. Brown called [Random Number Generation with Arbitrary Strides](https://laws.lanl.gov/vhosts/mcnp.lanl.gov/pdf_files/anl-rn-arb-stride.pdf) which extensively deals with this topic.

As Nabb stated in the comments, a **Linear Congruential Generator** can be used for efficient skipping. Of course, the usual [advantages and disadvantages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_congruential_generator#Advantages_and_disadvantages_of_LCGs) of LNGs apply: the thing's simple and blazingly fast, but the pseudo-random numbers are not of very high quality. The formula is explained [here](https://www.nayuki.io/page/fast-skipping-in-a-linear-congruential-generator) in detail.

Answer (score 2):

You can certainly jump in xorshift, and the process is described [here](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1404.0390.pdf), but I haven't read that for myself so I don't know how easy it is to follow.

Alternatively, you could look at [PCG](http://www.pcg-random.org/) which offers a jump function by using an underlying LCG (the same as @Daerst's answer) but post-processes it to improve its statistical properties, or some of the splittable generators described [here](http://on-demand.gputechconf.com/gtc/2016/presentation/s6665-guy-steele-fast-splittable.pdf).  The SplitMix generator, for example, has only an in-loop addition of a constant, so to jump an arbitrary distance you need only multiply the jump distance by the constant and add that ([here](http://xoroshiro.di.unimi.it/splitmix64.c)'s a SplitMix derivitive that apparently passes BigCrush).

Answer (score 1):

You could use a hierarchy of random number generators. I.e. Every number you generate with generator A is used as a seed for generator B, which generates i.e. 100 numbers before it takes the next number from A to reinitialize itself and generates the next 100 numbers etc.. This way you could skip forward in steps by 100. You can of course cascade this into a tree of generators.

Comment: Great tip, thank you! Still, I'd like to know if there's a mathematical approach to skipping ahead with Xorshift, or a RNG that's designed for fast skip ahead.